# av_log function in ffmpeg to output to a file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am logging time-stamps, and frames using av_log() to the console. Unfortunately, the console does not pipe to a file.

I would appreciate to know if there is a way to add function or other options to log to the file directly, instead of the console.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Tilak

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will have to set a logging callback function using [`av_log_set_callback()`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__log.html#ga14034761faf581a8b9ed6ef19b313708). In your callback you can format the log message as you desire and then write it to a file. The callback is your own function which matches the signature of the default callback:

```
void av_log_default_callback    (   void *      avcl,
        int     level,
        const char *    fmt,
        va_list     vl 
    )
```

Answer (score -2):

You might want to redirect by doing 2>&1

Eg:

```
ffmpeg -i a.flv -acodec copy -vcodec copy b.mp4 &>test.log
```

Note the redirection **&>** will redirect all stdout and stderr output to a file.
Reference: http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf

EDIT: command updated.

Comment: He is asking how to do that through the C API, not with bash.

Comment: @ Timothy_G, Not exactly.he already uses c api to get log,but facing issue to write a file. and also,his question says, "is a way to add function or other options to log to the file directly".If u still think my answer is inappropriate then leave it otherwise u can remove -1.

Comment: Thanks Timothy and Balamurugan for the comments. My goal was initially to use the C API, but I am using the stderr from console to a file.. I wanted to check the logs, but would be tidy to print to a file from the API..

Comment: @TilakVarisetty,So, at present are you able to  pipe to a file? Coz, I see in ur question, "the console does not pipe to a file", in such case, my answer could have helped you.

Comment: @Balamurugan: Yes, I am able to pipe now to the stdout file.. I had problems before to do it. thank you for the answer :)

Comment: If my answer helped consider to upvote. If you want specific taged message to be written into a file, u can do with grep and tee, command too. Eg. Try running, ffmpeg -v debug  2>&1|grep subtable >log.txt